# Betfair - Result After Match Completion

Tags: php, laravel, betfair

I have implemented Betfair PHP API for my Site, I fetch all Matches and Its running Odds using [Developer Program Betfair](https://developer.betfair.com/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Betting+Type+Definitions).

I am facing problem, with fetching result of particular selection from particular market on match completion.

Is there any `API endpoint` to find at which Odd(Rate) a particular Selection Passed or Fails.

Kindly Provide Some Suggestions,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "passed or fails"?

Comment: Did you get any solution @mayank-majithya ?

Comment: Not, yet @volvereabhi